# Fail to activate network, even manually

Tags: debian, networking, ifconfig

I'm in the middle of a nightmarish Debian upgrade.
The latest problem I have, after a reboot is that I get dropped in single user mode and the network won't come up.

1st question: how do I know the reason for ending in single user mode?

Now about the network: I see eth0 with `ifconfig -a`, and I tried to activate it manually with:

```
# ifconfig eth0 134... netmask 255...
# route add default gw 134... eth0
```

`ifconfig` just shows 0 packets. Curiously `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` shows 0 but the cable is connected. `dmesg | grep eth` shows the proper drivers (I can't copy paste from the console but: `bnx2x QLogic 5771x/578xx` and `eth0: Tigon3...`) and the tg3 driver seems loaded with `lsmod`... Curiously:

```
# ifup eth0
ifup: unknown interface eth0
```

The `systemctl restart networking` seems fine. I also tried activating the DHCP and it just hangs at the discovery stage.

What else can I try ?

Comment: `dmesg` should tell you what happened during boot

Comment: Take a note, Debian migrates to Consistent Network Device Naming (something like enp3s2 instead of eth0). And instead of `ifconfig` the preferred command is `ip` (`ip a` shows all interfaces status). eth0 could remain on the base of udev rules.Sometimes there is a NetworkManager subsystem mainly used together with Desktop Environment (Gnome, KDE ...). On server I usually uninstall it.

Comment: I don't see any nm* tools. The basic ip commands I've tried don't seem to add to the situation. Anything I should try ? One weird thing is that the switch doesn't see the mac address of the system.

Comment: That interface is down. Do `ip link show` and `ip link set dev eth0 up`

Comment: `ip link...` doesn't write anything. `link show`: `NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000`. The switch DOES see the connection but does NOT receive a MAC address. I tried another eth card, same results. What linux service provides the mac address to the network ?

Comment: Check `dmesg`.  Most likely your NIC requires a firmware file and the kernel can't find it.  See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware